# Closing an application gently and waiting for it exit

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, process, exit

Somewhere in the application I create a instance of `proc` which is of [`Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) type, something like this:

```
 proc = new Process();
 proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
 proc.StartInfo.FileName = Settings.Instance.OBSExeFile;
 proc.Exited += (a, b) => doSomething();
 proc.Start();
 proc.WaitForInputIdle();
```

on [`Form.Closing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing(v=vs.110).aspx) Event, I want to close it, gently, if it's still open.

I find no other way to do this with native stuff within the .NET (neither `Close()` nor `Kill()` nor `CloseMainWindow()` seemed to fit my needs) so I eneded up doing sending [`WM_CLOSE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632617(v=vs.85).aspx) to the application and calling `Process.WaitForExit()`, like this:

```
if (proc != null && !proc.HasExited) {
    if(SendMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, WM_CLOSE, 0, IntPtr.Zero) == 0)
        proc.WaitForExit();
}
```

My question is: Am I missing something in the sense of mixing this being dangerous in *any* way? Can `WaitForExit()`hang for ever, for example?

Comment: Asking if you are "missing something" is way too broad. There are lots of things you _could_ be missing; unless you've provided every last detail of your entire research effort in the post above, there's no way to know what you might have overlooked. If you have provided every last such detail, then you haven't done enough research. Can `WaitForExit()` hang? Of course...you have no guarantee any given process will exit when you send `WM_CLOSE` to its window. Any cooperatively-closing mechanism will suffer the same risk; it's why Windows offers a timeout for processes that don't close when told

Answer (score 0):

send a message to it, and have it close itself (in any way that you see fit).  I have a set of programs that do this, I use a udp broadcast to 127.0.0.1 for this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided I think good approach will be create a Windows service instead of .exe. Then you will have full control of process.

Inside windows service you can create a code which "gently" close current service when `stop` command will be send to it.